# "could" in the past referring to a single possibility/opportunity

Tags: grammar, past-tense, modal-verbs

I decided to create another question as this addresses another aspect of the topic I discussed in my related questions.

I know that in general, "could" is not used to describe a specific possibility in the past - I should not say "I could buy the car yesterday" when I mean that I had a chance/opportunity to buy. For that, "could have bought" should be used.

> He dropped the heavy Tenontosaurus and faked an attack at the male,
>   they both fell for it and the Aerosteon ran past them. Now he **could**
>   run away if he wanted to.

In this case, I believe the could does express a single possibility/opportunity in the past, and the usage is correct. However, I do not know what usage is this, it just refer to the past, so according to one comment it is a hypothetical scenario in the present/future?

I tried to reproduce the pattern but it does not feel right:

> I went to the dealership and test drove the car. I could
>   buy it but I decided not to.

Could this be changed so that it works with simple "could" as the dinosaur example above?

Comment: *Now he could run away if he wanted to.* is a good example of hypothetical occurrence in the present, or future. It's nothing to do with the past.

Comment: @LucianSava Even though the whole narrative is in the past, so the context is in the past?

Comment: Yes, in the past, you are just switching the mood, from indicative to conditional.

Comment: @LucianSava And the first example is ok too?

Comment: Not sure about the first example, that's why I did not produce an answer.